# How to remove same session value for different sessions?

Tags: security, session

I received an error from the Security testing team as follows:

*It was observed that same session value is used for different sessions. After logout, session value should be cleared and the user should be provided a new session value every time user logs in. 
It was observed that every time user login the session value was set to the following value "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"*

How to rectify this? What would be the best approach to avoid these kind of issues?

Comment: The cookie that SharePoint gives users has a timeout. What authentication method are you using?

Comment: Yes, normally it should timeout and probably the session value should be reset or changed I believe. The authentication method used is Windows.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET does not always give a unique session ID.  If no data is written to the session, ASP.NET may reuse the ID.

Here is an article explaining this: http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2004/09/13/228713.aspx

I would advise working with the sec. team to try to get a replicable (simple) example of when this occurs to identify why the session Ids are being reused.

Check for trends such as web browser, time logged in etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out : [Setting the Login Token Expiration Correctly for SharePoint 2010 SAML Claims Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147183.aspx)